# How to make an expandable table view cell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, toggle, expandable

I would like a table view cell which when you tap it grows in height to reveal some description text. When you tap it again it toggles back to the less tall version. Is this possible, and if so how would I accomplish it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

--

In

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

when the user taps on a row, set the new row height in an array somewhere, then call tableview reload to redraw.  It will call cellForRowAtIndexPath and since you know which cell has a large height, you return the larger cell for that row, and heightForRowAtIndexPath will ensure it is displayed correctly.

Comment: Ah, thanks, looks good. Do you know how I could make it animate, or will that do that?